# correct way to pass args by reference and update their values inside a function

Tags: c++, multithreading, pass-by-reference

I am writing a program in c++ that uses a queue of bind tasks and a threadpool that fetches tasks from the queue. The threads must perform operations between a matrix and a vector and write the result into another vector.

the problem is that when the function executed by the thread exits, no new values have been written into the vector. What is the right way to pass the arguments by reference and update them?

```
mutex ll;
condition_variable cond;
bool stop = false;
    
deque<function<void()>> bind_tasks;
// initialize the vector with all zeroes
vector<double> x(n, 0.0), new_x(n, 0.0);

auto bind_submit = [&] (function<void()> f){
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(ll);
        bind_tasks.push_back(f);
    }
    cond.notify_all();
};


auto body = [&](int tid){
    while(true){
        function<void()> t = []() {return 0; };
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> lock(ll);
            cond.wait(lock,
                      [&]() { return (!bind_tasks.empty() || stop); }
            );
            if (!bind_tasks.empty()) {
                t = bind_tasks.front();
                bind_tasks.pop_front();
            }

            if (stop)
                return;
        }
        t();
    }
};


// executed by the threads
auto f = [&](vector<vector<double>> matrix, vector<double> x,
        vector<double> b, vector<double> new_x, int i, int n){

    int sum = 0;
    // use the values of x and writes on new_x
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
        sum = matrix[i][j] * x[j];
    }
    new_x[i] = (b[i] - sum) / matrix[i][i];

};

vector<thread> tids(nw);

for(int tid=0; tid<nw; tid++){
    tids[tid] = thread(body, tid);
}


for(int it=0; it<k; it++){
    for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
        auto fx = (bind(f, matrix, x, b, new_x, i, n));
        bind_submit(fx);
    }

    //function that prints the vector
    print_vector(new_x); //it is still all zeroes
    
    x=new_x;
}
```

Comment: Lot of compiler errors in the code given. Note that every change people have to make in order to properly investigate your code is a chance for a new mistake to be inserted (and useless answers will be written based on those new mistakes) or the mistake to be accidentally fixed (and you get no answer). It's  in your best interests to provide a code example tat people can drop into their tools, compile, run, and, withing reasonable expectations of possible undefined behaviour, see what you see. Use [mre] for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to pass args by reference is *drumm roll* to actually pass args by reference.

```
auto f = [&](vector<vector<double>> matrix, vector<double> x,
    vector<double> b, vector<double> new_x, int i, int n){ ... }
```

All the arguments are passed by value. You also bind everything else by reference and never use it.

I think you are missundestanding what `[&]` does.

Your lambda doesn't need to bind anything, just pass arguments as reference.

```
auto f = [](const vector<vector<double>> & matrix, const vector<double> & x,
    cost vector<double> & b, vector<double> & new_x, int i, int n){ ... }
```

Comment: Please provide the OP with correct syntax. Repeating the erratic code will not help him learn.